# Gotchas with SQL Server Full-Text Search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I want to compile a list of gotchas when using SQL Server full-text search in all versions.

For instance, Here's a SQL Server Full-Text gotcha:

> SQL Server 2008 R2 has a new feature
>   called Data-Tier Applications - which
>   is a way to package a database schema
>   meant to be deployed elsewhere.
>   Certain objects like Full-Text
>   Catalogs can't be packaged and must
>   first be remove before a "DAC Pack"
>   can be created. So you can't create a
>   DAC Pack when there's a Full-Text
>   Catalog in the database.

Can anyone else think of any other SQL Server Full-Text gotchas? Thanks.

Comment: Kendal Van Dyke notes a glitch in SSMS 2008 when using it to script a Full-Text Catalog for a previous version of SQL Server including SQL Server 2005. It seems simple to avoid, however. Just use SSMS 2005. The note is here: http://kendalvandyke.blogspot.com/2009/04/full-text-catalog-scripting-in-ssms.html

Comment: One thing to note is that I'm not looking for rants against the technology - but known, repeatable trade-offs and issues to keep in mind - things that if known up-front, might help make the decision about whether or not to implement Full-Text search in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

If you detach a database with a full text catalog, the catalog is not a part of the normal database files, it has its own storage in a folder that has to be copied with the database mdf, ldf, and ndf files.  I've seen this be a problem for some people but it is recoverable.